# How to connect paired bluetooth device on app startup in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is there any way to automatically connect a specific device via Bluetooth LE on app startup?

I've been scrolling through stack overflow for the past few hours and have seen a number of similar questions, although majority are quite outdated and deal with reflections or other complex methods that I can't quite comprehend (these methods I've tried to implement, but not successfully, as I didn't really understand what was going on).

So far, I've managed to find the device by its friendly name, although I have no clue what to execute in that if statement. This is within my MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth not supported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size()>0){
            for(BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices){

                if (deviceName.equals(device.getName())) {

                    //Device found!
                    //Now how do I pair it?

                    break;
                }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up scrolling through the source code for [this app](https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothLeTerminal), particularly the SerialSocket, SerialService and SerialListener files which completely solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've successfully identified the `BlueToothDevice`, you now need to connect to the GATT(Generic Attribute Profile), which allows you to transfer data.


Use the `BlueToothDevice.connectGatt` method. Using the first overload, the method takes in a `Context` , a boolean (false = directly connect, true = connect when available), and a `BlueToothGhattCallback`. The callback receives info from the device.

```
BlueToothGatt blueToothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, blueToothGattCallback);
```

An example to implement the callback:

```
BluetoothGattCallback blueToothGattCallback =
   new BluetoothGattCallback() 
   {
       @Override
       public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
          if(newState == BlueToothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){ 
              /* do stuff */
          }
       }

   }
```

More details on the callbacks [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback).